# Need to get information for java heap size java 6

Tags: java, windows, websphere, java-6

I have java 6 on ibm clearquest
I need to get information and monitoring for java heap size for Ibm clearquest application
I test this command 
`java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"`
not working but it is working with java 7

Comment: try [jmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)

Comment: please send me an example

Comment: there are examples in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html). plenty of online resources. make use of your favorite search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with IBM Java, you can use `-verbose:gc` to generate GC logging that shows the heap size and usage over time. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/mm_gc_pd_verbosegc.html

Please note also that IBM Java 6 is no longer supported:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2/earlier_releases/earlier_releases.html

Newer supported IBM Java versions are available:
https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/

Comment: please send me an example